# Grouping and displaying values in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have grouped object inside an array according to specific property (in my case location.title).

```
let grouped = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(homes.items, "location.title"),
  x => x.map(y => _.omit(y, "location.title"))
);
```

Output result is as :

```
New York: (2) [{...}{...}]
Washington: (3)[{...}{...}{...}]
```

my Question is how can i map this output array and get output like this in React app.

Homes in New York :
  Here goes NewYork homes

Homes in Washington:
 Here goes Washington homes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) on the `grouped` object to get an array of all the keys, and then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on that array to render them separately.

```
<div>
  {Object.keys(grouped).map(key => (
    <div key={key}>Homes in {key}: {grouped[key].join(', ')}</div>
  ))}
</div>
```

```js
function App() {
  const grouped = {
    'New York': ['foo', 'bar'],
    Washington: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(grouped).map(key => (
        <div key={key}>Homes in {key}: {grouped[key].join(', ')}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: so {grouped[key]} will pull out object inside particular array and i can passed down this object to React Component as props in order to display this with all its props like images, contents etc

Comment: @IramAkhtar Yes, `Object.keys(grouped)` results in a new array with all the keys in `grouped`, so `grouped[key]` will be `grouped['New York']` for the first iteration of `map`, and so on. If `grouped[key]` is an object, you can pass that down to another component as props if you like.

Comment: my grouped[key] resulting another array containing objects of homes like this.   (2) [{...}{...}] (3) [{...}{...}{...}]     I need to display this array of objects along side of each location.